# Resizing array to lose empty values

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I have made a loop that loops for every month from a current age through year x, say 80.

I have an array yearCalculation years and every yearCalculation contains among other things an array of monthCalculation. *(Just in case anyone wants to throw a comment about Lists, I am currently using arrays and want to see if there is an easy solution.)*

This looks as following:

```
yearCalculations[] years = years.InstantiateArray(//Number of years, [80 minus age]//);
monthCalculations[] months = months.InstantiateArray(//Number of months in a year, [this should be 12]//);
```

After the instantiation I loop through all the periods and fill them with all sorts of calculations. (**However, after age x is being reached, all calculations will result in zero**):

```
for (int i = 0; i < yearCalculations.Length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < yearCalculations[i].monthCalculations.Length; j++) {
        Double age = calculateAge(birthDate, dateAtTimeX);
        if(age < ageX){
            //Do all sorts of calculations.
        }else{
            //Break out of the loops
        }
    }
}
```

As you can understand at age X (80), the calculations will be complete, but the last yearcalculation will contain some results, without calculations being made. Lets say this is from month 7 and on. What is the easiest way to resize this array, removing all the months without calculations (So index 6 and on)?

---

Just for the sake of completeness, here is the instantiateArray function;

```
public static T[] InstantiateArray<T>(this T[] t, Int64 periods) where T : new() 
{
    t = new T[periods];
    for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++){
        t[i] = new T();
    }
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Seriously, why don't you use `List<T>` for this? There's not much reason to use arrays, especially when you need to resize them.

Comment: @JonSkeet What is so horrible about the extension method? It does work for the purpose it is intended.

Comment: @Sliver2009: It doesn't use the existing value at all - you're presumably only using it for the purpose of type inference... I don't view that as a nice use for an extension method, personally. (I'm surprised it even works in the code you're using it with - you're declaring a variable and using it in its own initializer, which shouldn't compile.)

Comment: I am using it for type inference. It works and it is better, in my opinion, than write the same code for 10 different classes. So pardon my french; but I do not mind whether u think it looks nice or not, just out of personal beliefs.

Comment: I didn't suggest writing the same code multiple times - I just wouldn't bother with the type inference. Or at least you should edit the question to show how you'd use it in a way that compiles. I'd also make the type names in the question follow .NET idioms. But of course, you're very welcome to ignore my opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To remove blank values from the array you could use LINQ

```
var arr = years.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();//or what ever you need
```

Comment: Very nice, I am using LINQ all the time. I was just not aware of the fact that I could use it on arrays to. (Now you mention it, I feel really stupid!)

Comment: FYI it works on anything that implements `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 2):

**You can't resize an array.**

[To quote MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx)

> The number of dimensions and the length of each dimension are established when the array instance is created. These values can't be changed during the lifetime of the instance.

What methods like Array.Resize actually do is allocate a new array and copy the elements over. It's important to understand that. You're not resizing the array, but reallocating it.

So long as you're using arrays, in the end the answer is going to boil down to "allocate a new array, then copy what you want to keep over to it".

Comment: I know I can not 'literally' resize an array. But it is figure of speaking, I am fully aware that it creates another instance.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry then. But please avoid using the term "resize" in the future, unless it's what you really mean.

Answer (score 1):

The [Array.Resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb348051(v=VS.110).aspx) method should do the trick with the new total length. You know the total new length to be the total old length - (12 - month as an int in year)